# How to get the detailed error in web api Authentication Failed scenario instead of "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, bearer-token, webapi

I created a web api from VS template with a Values Controller decorated with [Authorize]. I have added Owin Startup as below:

```
[assembly: OwinStartup(typeof(WebAPIDotNet.Startup))]
namespace WebAPIDotNet
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private static string clientId = "xxxxxxxxx"; // my actual client id from azure ad.

        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {


            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AccessTokenFormat = new JwtFormat(
                    new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        // Check if the audience is intended to be this application
                        ValidAudiences = new[] { clientId, $"api://{clientId}" },

                        // Change below to 'true' if you want this Web API to accept tokens issued to one Azure AD tenant only (single-tenant)
                        // Note that this is a simplification for the quickstart here. You should validate the issuer. For details, 
                        // see https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-native-aspnetcore
                        ValidateIssuer = false,

                    }

                    //new OpenIdConnectSecurityTokenProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration")
                    ),
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
// Below Provider is just so that I can capture detailed errors while debugging, but no success
                    Provider = new OAuthBearerAuthenticationProvider
                    {
                        OnRequestToken = Onrequesttoken,
                        OnApplyChallenge = applyuingChallenge,
                        OnValidateIdentity = validatingidentiity

                    },
                });

            }

            private Task validatingidentiity(OAuthValidateIdentityContext arg)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            private Task applyuingChallenge(OAuthChallengeContext arg)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }

            private Task Onrequesttoken(OAuthRequestTokenContext arg)
            {
                return Task.FromResult(0);
            }
        }
    }
```

I have an access token already, and I have validated that it has the correct audience, etc. But making a GET request with Postman keeps giving me the msg - "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request."

When i debug I can see the token as part of the Authorization, is there any way i can log/see actual error rather than "Message": "Authorization has been denied for this request." ?

Postman request:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone else runs into this, I found the answer in Owin Katana docs. Essentially placing below config in your web.config will enable logs in the output window with details and I was able to see the underlying reason of failed authorization since I am using the Owin auth middleware.

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <switches>
      <add name="Microsoft.Owin" value="Verbose" />
    </switches>
  </system.diagnostics>
```